# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed when using requests

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, python-requests, postman

I am trying to send data via API but am receiving a SSL Certificate Verify Failed error with the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://urlhere"

payload = "name=Test&description=Test&deadline=2017-12-31&disableEmail=true&campaignFilterId=00ad9cac28fa4c29fdb641c64b007a0b&type=Manager"

headers = {
    'x-csrf-token': "TVUmiEALzVRQDkoQWbzdLI6l6NgftGoU",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'cache-control': "no-cache",
    'postman-token': "f8a9c488-0402-be25-aefb-cb2df65897f3"
    }

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am aware of using "verify=False" but understand that is not a recommended work around. What could be wrong here? I don't think it is the server since when I run this same API call in Postman it runs without issue.

Comment: Different tools and libraries (i.e. postman vs. Python requests) using different trust stores. Thus, succeeding validation in postman does not mean that it succeeds doing validation in Python requests. The problem is specific with  the URL and maybe your Python installation - but both are not given in the question.

Comment: I've edited the question with that information. I am using Python 3.6.0.

Comment: The site seems to be correctly configured, i.e. no server side problems. It works for me also with Python without exception. My guess is that you are behind some SSL intercepting firewall which changes the original certificate. This causes a certificate failure if the CA of this firewall/proxy is not explicitly added as trusted.

Comment: This seems plausible, thanks for the help, will look into it and update question if necessary.